# Posting to user's wall with Facebook PHP SDK - how to populate "shared a link via BLANK"?

Tags: php, facebook

VERY long story short, we cannot place og meta tags on the pages from which we want to share links to Facebook, as we're embedded on other peoples' sites. For various reasons and because of unresolved bugs and undocumented changes in some of Facebook's sharing features, we're resorting to posting to the current user's feed via the Facebook PHP SDK. This is an example of the code...

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => FACEBOOK-APPID,
    'secret' => FACEBOOK-SECRET,
    'fileUpload' => false
  ));

$user = $facebook->api('/me');

$params = array(
    'caption' => 'Some caption',
    'description' => 'This is the fine, fine description.',
    'from' => array('id' => $user['id'], 'name' => $user['name']),
    'link' => VALID-URL,
    'name' => 'Link Name Here',
    'picture' => VALID-IMAGE-URL
  );

$response = $facebook->api('me/feed', 'POST', $params);
```

This successfully posts to the current user's wall. $response contains an ID confirming it. Below is a cropped screenshot of the post on the user's Timeline.

[image: The resulting post]

"shared a link via BLANK."

The question is... what is BLANK and how do I fill it?

A little extra info:

All parameters are taken from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post

After adding the "actions" parameter with a 'name' and 'link' values, BLANK was replaced with the name of the Facebook App being used, however the link is now displayed with a slightly smaller thumbnail image and if the user posts other links they are merged into a combined post, which is not desirable.

Comment: FYI, the `.` appearing instead of the name of the app is a bug, tracking here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/640453342670536/ - the name of your Facebook app should be appearing there, as it does in News Feed and on the permalink for that post - the Timeline display of the post isn't working correctly right now

Comment: Oh my. And to think I was only using this method because of another FB bug left assigned but unresolved for 3 months. I hope *one* of them is fixed soon! I'd say your comment is the correct answer. If you post is as an answer I'll gladly mark it is such. Thanks!