# "shared a link via" is blank using Android FacebookShareDialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

On the user's Facebook wall, when I publish a share using the FacebookShareDialog the top line does not show the Application Name as it should.  It just shows `USERNAME shared a link via .` (note the period and no Application Name).  This is not an issue on the feed, but does affect others users if they view my wall directly.

[image: Blank application name in Facebook share]

Here is the code I am using:

```
if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(), FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
                    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder((Activity) context)
                        .setLink(Constants.SHARE_URL)
                        .setName(Constants.SHARE_TITLE)
                        .setCaption(Constants.SHARE_CAPTION)
                        .setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name))
                        .build();
                    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
                } else {
                    final Intent shareIntent = BaseUtils.getShareIntentForUrl(Constants.SHARE_URL, Constants.SHARE_TITLE);
                    Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.share_intent_title));
                    startActivity(shareIntent);
                }`
```

So my question is, how do I fill in the Application Name in that line?  It fills in appropriately in share posts when other users see it on their wall, so I know the Facebook Share Dialog is "getting" the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that this is a known Facebook bug, rather than specific to the Facebook Android SDK, as it happens for other apps as well.

https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/640453342670536/

PHP StackOverflow question: [Posting to user's wall with Facebook PHP SDK - how to populate "shared a link via BLANK"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542976/posting-to-users-wall-with-facebook-php-sdk-how-to-populate-shared-a-link-vi)